# Laravel - Request Validation to Image set as Nullable is not allowed and gives error why?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I need to validate my image array as an image and specific image file extensions only. but my request validation to image WONT ALLOW me to use inser nullable values

For example I will add a content and dont want to add images. then the image should contain null that is why i need to have request validation as nullable. But in my experience null value is not allowed and it gives me error why? help me please

here is the error.

> ***Undefined variable: promotion***

here is my ***CONTROLLER***

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'promotion_image' => 'image|nullable|max:1999'
        ]);

        if ($request->has('promotion_image'))
        {   
            //Handle File Upload

            $promotion = [];
            foreach ($request->file('promotion_image') as $key => $file)
            {
                // Get FileName
                $filenameWithExt = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                //Get just filename
                $filename = pathinfo( $filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                //Get just extension
                $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                //Filename to Store
                $fileNameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
                //Upload Image
                $path = $file->storeAs('public/promotion_images',$fileNameToStore);
                array_push($promotion, $fileNameToStore);
            }

            $fileNameToStore = serialize($promotion);
        }
        else
        {
            $fileNameToStore='noimage.jpg';
        }

        if (count($promotion)) {
            $implodedPromotion = implode(' , ', $promotion);
            $promotionImage = new Promotion;
            $promotionImage->promotion_image = $implodedPromotion;
            $promotionImage->save();

            return redirect('/admin/airlineplus/promotions')->with('success', 'Image Inserted');
        }

        return redirect('/admin/airlineplus/promotions')->with('error', 'Something went wrong.');


        }
```

here is my ***VIEW***

```
    {!! Form::open(['action'=>'Admin\PromotionsController@store', 'method' => 'POST','enctype'=>'multipart/form-data', 'name' => 'add_name', 'id' => 'add_name']) !!}
<div class="form-group">   
    <div class="table-responsive">  
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">  
           <tr>  
              <td> {{ Form::file('promotion_image[]')}}</td>

              <td>{{ Form::button('', ['class' => 'btn btn-success fa fa-plus-circle', 'id'=>'add','name'=>'add', 'style'=>'font-size:15px;']) }}</td>
           </tr>  
        </table>  
        {{Form::submit('submit', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary', 'name'=>'submit'])}}
    </div> 
</div>  
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: what if you remove nullable from request validation.

Comment: I cannot I need to include nullable validation if ever I dont want to add an image.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare `$promotion = []` above `if ($request->has('promotion_image'))`, not inside of it.

So:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'promotion_image' => 'image|nullable|max:1999'
    ]);

    $promotion = [];

    if ($request->has('promotion_image'))
    {   
        //Handle File Upload
```

Comment: Hey I thought it worked but it throws me an error again .. **The promotion image must be an image.** ..

Comment: did you set enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form??

Comment: That is a different error. You were getting `Undefined variable: promotion` because you were trying to access `$promotion` when it wasn't declared.

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head, `nullable` should allow it to be `null`. Inspect what you're getting in the request. Also you should probably accept this as the correct answer to your initial question.

Answer (score 0):

That is because your selecting file other than image in your form. See the following to restrict user to only upload images.

```
<input accept=".png, .jpg, jpeg" name="files[]" type="file" multiple>
```

Comment: any solution? what will I do?

Comment: still does not work :( I think the serialize function gives trouble cause it return as string... the error is it cannot be defined as an image

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but try once

```
'promotion_image' => 'nullable|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif|max:1999'
```